# java sql insert timestamp java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, derby

i am trying to insert `timestamp` to my database but i keep getting `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`:

here is my code

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
System.out.println(sqlDate);
```

Here the insertion and connection to DB

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1598/VotingDB", "app", "app");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO VOTES (CANDIDATE_NAME,VOTER_SSN,TIMESTAMP) "
            + "VALUES ('" + Candidate_Name + "','" + ssn + "'," + TimeStamp + ")";

    st.executeUpdate(sql);
    st.close();
    conn.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("Connection failed adding vote " + ex);
}
```

**Error**

> 2017-04-09 20:10:02.825  Connection failed adding vote
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "20" at
>   line 1, column 94.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to put your time between `''`  like this :

```
"VALUES ('" + Candidate_Name + "','" + ssn + "', ' " + TimeStamp + "')";
```

But this is not secure enough, you have to use PreparedStatement instead to avoid any SQL Injection.

For example :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO VOTES (CANDIDATE_NAME, VOTER_SSN, TIMESTAMP) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    stm.setString(1, Candidate_Name );
    stm.setString(2, ssn );
    stm.setDate(3, TimeStamp);

    stm.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you enclose TimeStamp variable in simple quotes?

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO VOTES (CANDIDATE_NAME,VOTER_SSN,TIMESTAMP) "
  + "VALUES ('"+Candidate_Name +"','"+ssn +"','"+TimeStamp+"')";
```